# Calculate an improper integral

Tags: integration

I have difficulties to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{[y,\infty)} \sin(\frac{\pi y}{2x}) \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dxdy$$

The first idea is to do the following:
$\int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{[y,\infty)} \sin(\frac{\pi y}{2x}) \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dxdy=\int_{[y,\infty)} [-\frac{2}{\pi}\cos(\frac{\pi y}{2x})]_0^\infty e^{-x}dx=\int_{[y,\infty)} [-\frac{2}{\pi}\cos(\frac{\pi y}{2x})]_0^\infty e^{-x}dx$.

But it doesn't work since $\cos(\infty)$ ist not defined. Unfortunately I have no other ideas. :(
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the integration order
$$\int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{[y,\infty)} \sin\left(\frac{\pi y}{2x}\right) \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx\,dy
=\int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{[0,x]} \sin\left(\frac{\pi y}{2x}\right)\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dy\,dx$$